# A beggar forced me to give money

Tags: india, trespass, indian-penal-code, blackmail

**Backstory:**
A beggar beat (very hard) the gate of my room (a rental room in a residential building). I opened the gate and refused to give money. When I tried to close the door they forcefully entered inside my room and threatened/blackmailed me that if I don't give them money they'll remove their clothes and sit on my bed. I said it's not justified to force someone but they challenged me to call the police. They also used various vulgar words and gestures against me.

Other people of the building asked me to give money (that's what society makes you do). Finally I gave them money, unwillingly; though the amount was not significant.

---

**Points I noted**

- Coercion/blackmailing for money
- Invading my private space
- Using vulgar words and gestures against me

**Questions**

- Can someone suggest me how to deal with such coercive tactics of begging?
- What are my options against someone invading my private space?

And this isn't a simple case of beggary but it violates my fundamental rights such as rights of freedom and privacy among others.

Comment: Which state is this in? Some have anti-begging laws and some don't.

Comment: Madhya Pradesh (India)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the constitution of India

Comment: This is straight out of Elder Scrolls. Sorry, man!

Comment: Given the urgency of the situation, you did the right thing by giving this person money.  A "insignificant" amount solved the immediate problem, good job.  However, the police should be contacted so this does not happen in the future.

Comment: @Rick “Hijra” appears to be a legal terminology effectively meaning a third gender recognized under the law in India; is it deleted because it sounded offensive to us outsiders or is it deleted for the same reason beggar is not deleted? I’m not sure if beggar has a legal meaning.

Comment: Is there a reason not to call the police?

Comment: @kisspuska "Hijra" may be offensive word but "Kinnar" or Transgender is fine, however that was the key element of this whole incident. In India, due to social marginalization and exclusion, these people live in separate communities and almost always rely on begging and people give them money on special occasions and otherwise too (to get so called blessings or to avoid curses — similar to fairy tales). However what that person did to me was totally unacceptable. They can literally strip in front of you if you don't give money. So this makes them "unique kind of beggar"

Comment: @ohwilleke Whatever that person did was highly invasive. That person would have been behind the bars in any western country by now. But it's India, people have created discriminations and this makes those discriminated to choose to be "shameless" when begging. People have accepted - shameless behaviour, vulgar words & gestures etc as part of these transgender beggars. So this makes me a lone person failing to adjust in this social structure. I'm not gonna pursue any legal action. I feel like a loser in the crowd of idiots

Comment: @ShivCK did you know this when you used that word in your question?

Comment: @kisspuska this word is used by newspapers, dictionaries, and Wikipedia etc. This word is used by almost everyone. However it MAY BE considered offensive by some but it's definitely not a cuss word. However transgenders like to call themselves Kinnar - which is a word of a mythological origin. It's a word some might feel uncomfortable with in the same way as SEX and INTERCOURSE (hijra and kinnar/transgender).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Can someone suggest me how to deal with such coercive tactics of begging?**

One option is to report it to the police as begging in either a public or private place in [madhya-pradesh](/questions/tagged/madhya-pradesh) is an arrestable offence under [section 4](http://www.bareactslive.com/MP/MP102.HTM) of the *Madhya Pradesh Bhiksha Vritti Nivaran Adhiniyam, 1973*:

> **4. Power to require person found begging to appear before Court.**
>
> (1) Any police officer or other person authorised in this behalf in accordance with rules made by the State Government may arrest without a warrant any person who is found begging...

The Madhya Pradesh police have [on-line reporting](https://www.mppolice.gov.in/en/complaint-0) for lodging complaints. (my ability to read Hindi is very limited but that page seems relevant, if not try searching for "First Information Report".)

Answer (score 3):

I can't advise you what to do, that would be legal advice.

Let's look at a hypothetical situation:
An invader enters Owner's flat without the allowance of Owner by pushing aside Owner. Invader then threatens to spill the contents of a water bucket over Owner's bed and then tell the neighbors that the owner has a wet bed unless Owner gives Invader money.

First of all, entering that flat against Owner's wishes is not necessarily a violation of the constitution. The constitution protects before everything someone's rights against *the state*, not generally other citizens. While many rights against other citizens stem from it, citizens generally sue each other under other applicable laws that are derived from the constitution.

Owner's recourse against Invader stems from the ordinary law and in this case **Criminal Trespass**, [section 441 of the Indian Penal Code](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/1768645/):

> Whoever enters into or upon property in the possession of another [OP] with intent to commit an offence or to intimidate, insult or annoy any person in possession of such property, [...] is said to commit “criminal trespass”.

The prescribed sentence under [section 447](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/162506/) is imprisonment up to 3 months and/or a fine of 500 rupees.

The act of threatening to harm or destroy the bed is  commonly called "Blackmail" but the IPC defines it as **criminal intimidation** in [Section 503 of the IPC](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/878688/);  the pattern of "demanding money to not do something defamatory" also might fit **Extortion** under [Section 385 of the IPC](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/262864/):

> Criminal intimidation. — Whoever threatens another with any injury to his person, reputation or property, [...] to cause that person to do any act which he is not legally bound to do [like giving money], [...] as the means of avoiding the execution of such threat, commits criminal intim­idation.

> Extortion. - Whoever intentionally puts any person in fear of any injury to that person, or to any other, and thereby dishon­estly induces the person so put in fear to deliver to any person any property or valuable security, or anything signed or sealed which may be converted into a valuable security, commits “extor­tion”. Illustrations
>
> (a) A threatens to publish a defamatory libel concerning Z unless Z gives him money. He thus induces Z to give him money. A has committed extortion.

However, it is not robbery under [section 390 IPC](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/1905008/), as a bucket of water over the bed is not putting Owner under fear of death. As the illustration (d) shows, it is just Extortion:

> (d) A obtains property from Z by saying—“Your child is in the hands of my gang, and will be put to death unless you send us ten thousand rupees”. This is extortion, and punishable as such; but it is not robbery, unless Z is put in fear of the instant death of his child.

Comment: _"The constitution protects someone's rights against the state, not other citizens."_ — this statement of yours is wrong in context of the Constitution of India (CoI). As per CoI, there are many rights which protect an individual from others. Like right against untouchability (Article 17). However thanks for mentioning relevant IPC sections.

Comment: @ShivCK you mean "17. Abolition of Untouchability.—“Untouchability” is abolished and its
practice in any form is forbidden. The enforcement of any disability arising out
of “Untouchability” shall be an offence punishable in accordance with law." This is in general a prescription to the country/state to do something and forbidding them from taking a different stance. The relevant part for the citizen is more the separate *in accordance with law*, e.g. the specific law that outlaws certain acts that stem from the abolishment of *Untouchability*.

Comment: It's not mutually exclusive to have rights against arbitration actions of state and that of individuals. Regarding fundamental rights — `"3. All of them are available against the arbitrary action of the state. However some of them are also available against the action of private individuals."` — _M. Laxmikanth, Indian Polity 6th ed. (page 7.2)_. That's why I said fundamental rights can also be infringed by the actions of private individuals. I hope I made my point clear.

Comment: I see, yes! I hope the clarification makes it more clear: you generally don't sue someone for violating the constitution but for violating a law that is based on the constitution.